# Best testing tool to be used with OpenEdge 4GL Client

Tags: java, progress-4gl

Currently, I am working with AutoIT tool for automating the test cases and my client is OpenEdge 4GL (Progress). I have few problems in finding the elements on the screen like Instance changing frequently.

Can someone suggest me any other Testing Tool that can be used with Progress client for automating test cases?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 11.4 of OpenEdge there's a framework called "ABL Unit" shipped with the product.

This is however only for Unit style testing. Not automating gui tests.

[OE 11.5 documentation of ABL Unit.](https://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge115/openedge115/#page/pdsoe/overview-of-ablunit-testing-framework.html#)